# How to allow goog.html.sanitizer.HtmlSanitizer.Builder to permit the "placeholder" attribute

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I use `goog.html.sanitizer.HtmlSanitizer.Builder` to create safe HTML that I then dynamically insert into a dialog.  I wanted to have an input field that uses the Html 5 "placeholder" attribute.

I tried

```
.alsoAllowTagsPrivateDoNotAccessOrElse ([ "placeholder"])
```

and got an expected nasty compiler error!

Comment: Please edit your post and include the compilation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding the place holder attribute to the closure-library attribute white list javascript code.  The call to `alsoAllowTagsPrivateDoNotAccessOrElse` was removed and all worked well.

Comment: Where do you see a question in the answer? Am I missing it?